# get home or go home

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> Harry：Ooh, speaking of keeping busy----
>   I have an early start tomorrow,and the baby-sitter has to **get** home.
>   [He starts to put on his jacket.]
>   Where did the time go? It's midnight.
>   Thank you,Susan. I had a nice evening.
>
> Susan：Me, too, Harry.

I found an answer about the difference between "go home" and "get home" [here](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/25396).
I want to know if I can replace the *get* here with *go*, is it still logical?
Say I'm at a person's home and I'm going to go back to my own house, should I say *I have to go home* or *I have to get home*？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In colloquial English, both are frequently used. Grammatically, *go home* might be better, but *get home* might be heard more frequently.

Perhaps there's a minor difference in point of view -- *has to get home* implies the sitter has a personal need to be home, e.g. a pet to feed, while *has to go home* might point to an external reason; e.g. the sitter's parent has set a time to be back. And perhaps I'm reading too much into different ways to say the same thing.